# Is there a faster way to Search for the existence of an instance within a large collection then using Contains method?

Tags: c#, search

I have a C# console application that saves data to 2 db tables, an entity table and a Relation table. Each entity has Many-To-Many relationships with other entities. The Relations table stores a pair of IDs, which in turn are the primary key of the entity table.

Data in both tables should be unique. Initially I checked for this, prior to INSERTing new individial records in a database stored procedure. When the numbers starting getting larger in both tables (>50k in the entity table and >100k in the Relations table) I noticed that the performance really began to suffer.

I figured that going to the db to carry out checks for duplicate records was net helping performance due to added I/O costs so I refactored my code to, first, read both tables into memory and then carry out the checks there instead. This has increased performance although I suspect that it may still not be ideal. Here's how it looks now:

```
    private IEnumerable<long> _existingUsers = dao.GetUserIds();
    private IEnumerable<Relations> _existingRelations = dao.GetRelations();


                if (!_existingUsers.Contains(inputModel.ID))
                {
                    // db code to create the new Entity record
                }

                Relations rel = new Relations { Node = inputModel.Node, Follower = inputModel.ID };

                if (!_existingRelations.Contains(rel))
                {
                    // db code to create the new Relation entry
                }
```

Relations class:

```
public class Relations : IEquatable<Relations>
{
    public long Node { get; set; }
    public long Follower { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Relations other)
    {
        return (other.Node == this.Node) && (other.Follower == this.Follower);
    }
}
```

I can see via the Debugger that the majority of the time is now spent determining if the _existingRelations collection in memory Contains the "rel" instance. That in turn repeatedly hits the Equals method of the Relations class.

I suspect there may be a more efficient way to do this but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Is the collection sorted by the key? If so: binary search. Is it a dictionary/hash? Great: use that!

Comment: @MarcGravell Both collections are List<T>

Comment: and again: is it sorted? Being a list tells me nothing about whether it is sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the concrete implementation of the IEnumerable.

This is what happens when you call `contains` on a list. Searching in a list always iterated all the list to find an element. So there is no faster way to find one.

If you call this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1 then you'll get an `O(1)` as is the case for `HashSet` and dictionaries.

On the downside the hashset is not ordered.

Comment: Both collections are implemented as List<T>. OK, so If I instead use HashSet<T> it will be a lot faster?

Comment: Ok that brought my test example down from 129s -> 86s. Good stuff, thanks